# Write a sequence with certain traits.

Tags: sequences-and-series

I have to write sequence which is:

- not decreasing
- is bounded
- $n\rightarrow \infty : \lim a_n = \inf(a_n)$

I am unable to think of one, will you please help me? :)

Comment: Please can you use MathJaX? I add, for example, a tool: http://jbergknoff.github.io/mathjax-sandbox/#JFxpbnQgeCQgXFtcaW50IHggXF0%3D

Answer (score 1):

Let $a_{1}=1$, $a_{2n}=\dfrac{1}{2n}$ and $a_{2n+1}=\dfrac{1}{2n-1}$, this serves what you need.

Comment: +1 The idea here: take any sequence strictly decreasing to $0$ and swap tje terms at adjacent odd and even positions.

Comment: I cant get it, the sequence you wrote me is still decreasing isnt it?

Comment: Not really, for example, $a_{2}=1/2$ but $a_{3}=1>a_{2}$.

Comment: Well, a(3) should be 1/5 or am I completely dumb? :-D

Comment: For $a_{3}=a_{2\times 1+1}$, so you plug in $n=1$ into the formula, which gives you $1/(2\times 1-1)=1$.

Comment: Now I see it :). Wasnt used to this kind of description. Is it allright with definiton of limit, what I mean is that this sequence is jumping quite a lot and if it satisfies the definitinion of sequence limit. Is there any easier sequence which satisfies that criteria or I have to write it this way only? :)

Comment: Of course I cannot say this is the only way. But anyway, here's the philosophy which may make you feel easier to see: The even terms and odds terms are strictly decreasing, but the odd terms somehow slightly greater than the even terms consecutively, it brings you the feeling like the zig-zag, but they all tend to zero at the end.

Comment: So its not possible to write that sequence without using even terms and odd terms, right? What I mean we are unable to write some simple sequence a(n) which satisfies these conditions without some specific terms. Because if limit must be equal to infimum, then the sequence must be decreasing, since infimum can be -infinity or any real number.

Comment: I think there must be some other easier one, but I cannot figure out at the moment, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

$(0,1,0,\frac 1 2, 0, \frac 1 3,0, \frac 1 4,...)$ is such a sequence.

Comment: thx, now I see, for odd natural numbers it is a(n)=0 and for even it is a(n)=2/n. But I still wonder if it is ok with definiton of limit of sequence. There is some epsilon and it says, that from certain natural number 'n' every next number is closer to limit which is zero in this case. If we choose the first a(1)=0, then next is a(2)=1, but a(2) is farther from limit than a(1). However in the end, this sequence is approaching zero.

Comment: @naruto25 For the limit all that matters is what happens in the end. First few terms of the sequence don 't matter for the limit.

Comment: Could it be constant sequence? I know that constant sequence is defined as both increasing and decreasing(not sure if it fits the criteria).

Comment: @naruto25 You want  a sequence which is not decreasing so a constant sequence does not fit the bill.